# Where can I get a printed copy of the Open Group Base Specifications?

Tags: unix, printing, specifications

I find myself using the Open Group's base specifications quite a bit when I work. Using them online is fine, but I'd like to have a printed version.

I found the site [here](http://www.opengroup.org/bookstore/catalog/c082.htm), but the site says a printed version is unavailable. The html version is freely available, but the PDF requires paying a 4 figure membership fee, which I'm not able to do.

Is there anyway that I could parse the html pages and send them somewhere to be printed for me? Or does anyone know any other way I could get this in print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curl to download the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of hosted html to pdf conversion services that can do a quick and dirty conversion for you. [Here's](http://www.pdfonfly.com/) one I've used.

For a more professional job you'll have to download the html to your hard drive. You can then manipulate it to you heart's content. I would merge the webpages into a single word document and then use a pdf printer to generate the pdf (If your using open office you can just export directly to pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider wget and use this as a base URL:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/contents.html